# Rewrite the unit step function with a piecewise formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question: Rewrite the function

$f(t) = 5 + t^3 + u(t − 2)[e^{2t} − t^3]+ u(t − 4)[(t − 4)^3]$

without any unit step functions $u$; i.e., rewrite it with a piecewise formula.

My attempt: 
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&5+t^3 &&: t < 2 \\
&e^{2t}-t^3 &&: 2 \le t < 4\\
&(t-4)^3 &&: t \ge 4
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
However I don't know if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have stepped up doesn't mean that the other stuff has gone away.

$f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&5+t^3 &&: t < 2 \\
&e^{2t}+5 &&: 2 \le t < 4\\
&(t-4)^3 +e^{2t}+5&&: t \ge 4
\end{aligned}
\right.$